# Write a C++ struct to a file and read file using another programming language?

Tags: c++

I have a challenging situation; we will have programs on Mac, PC, iOS and Android receiving files in a legacy format and parsing data from those files. We cannot change how those files are created.

The files are produced by a C++ program filling a struct with numbers and Strings and then writing it out. Here's a sanitized version.

```
struct MyObject {
String Kfkj(MAXKYS); 
String Oern(MAXKYS);
String Vdflj(MAXKYS, 9); 
int Muic;
int Tdfkj;
int VdfkAsdk;
int SsdjsdDsldsk; 
int Ndsoief; 
String TdflsajPdlj; 
String TdckjdfPas; 
String AdsfakjIdd;
int IdkfjdKasdkj;
int AsadkjaKadkja(MAXKYS); 
int Kasldsdkj;
bool Usadl;
String PsadkjOasdj(9); 
String PasdkjOsdkj;
};
```

Primitives and Strings, as you can see.

Then here is how they write it out to a file:

```
MyInstance MyObject;
FileName = "C:\MyFile.ab2"
ofstream fout (FileName, ios::binary);
fout.write((char*)& MyInstance, sizeof(MyInstance));
```

There is no option for us to translate it once and then distribute the file to other platforms; we must translate it on each and every different platform, and this is what we have to work with.  I'd appreciate any information on how C++ serializes data, so we know how to parse the file.

EDIT: solution

The feedback I received from multiple answers here was VERY helpful. Using that, I did extensive analysis with hex editors and discovered:

- the elements come in the file one after another
- a "String," in this case, starts with an int describing how many characters follow the int for that String. If the String does not exist, it will still have that int with a value of 0.
- integers, for the files and machines I saw, are two bytes, little-endian, and MOSTLY unsigned (there were a few that were signed, just to keep me on my toes)
- the boolean was two bytes, with apparently -1 (FF FF) representing "true"

So far we have not ran into issues with different padding or endianness on different devices, but those are very real concerns. The skilled notes and warnings in these answers provides us with more ammunition to try to convince the client to change to a less fragile alternative, such as XML or JSON, for transferring data online across platforms.

As for those of you asking if the developer was fired... well, let's just say their code is very old, but after multiple conversations we're still having trouble convincing them writing out the C++ struct and trying to read that on different platforms is not a good idea.

Comment: C++ doesn't serialize data at all. That code writes it out however *your implementation* chooses to lay it out in memory.

Comment: Without a more precise definition of `String` this will be impossible.

Comment: Use Google Protocol Buffers, JSON, or BSON for cross-language serialization.

Comment: What is the machine that created these files?

Comment: If you use std::string, you will not be able to pull out the information properly. You need to make a char[] for strings or wide characters if you require unicode. Using the std::string class will only save the pointer you used to allocate the string data, but not the string itself.

Comment: Did the guy who wrote that got fired at some point ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to run into many problems.

C++ doesn't have a specific format for serializing data per se.  It is highly dependent on the computer architecture/processor that you are running on.

The compiler is allowed to add padding to help alignment on systems.  When we say alignment we basically are referring to an architecture/processor's affinity for having data lie on specific byte boundaries.  For example, some processors vastly prefer floating point numbers to lie at 4 or 8 byte boundaries - if they don't the processor may work much slower or may not work at all.

So, you can't simply know what padding your system is adding magically.

What you can do is use #pragma pack(1) / #pragma pack(0) to stop your compiler from padding your numbers.

PS: you also have to worry about endianness.  What if one computer is running on big-endian and one is little endian?  They will interpret bytes differently without a conversion.

Simply put, you either have to fix the application generating the files so it uses a proper serialization scheme OR you need to look at it running on a SPECIFIC computer, look at exactly how it writes the files, and write a translator for every target platform (which is just silly).

**Interesting Suggestion**

If you're really stuck, write an app that monitors the folder where you write files.  Have the app pick up the files (since it's on the same PC it'll be able to read their format without issue).  Have it write the files back in XML or some other true serialization format and distribute those instead.

Comment: They can't start adding pack pragmas now! That would change the file layout - and this is production code already! They should figure out what the layout is currently, and set it explicitly in the file writer.

Comment: I agree with you since he said he can't change it.  It doesn't simplify matters though, this file output may change every time he runs it on a new platform.  I added an edit with another idea though.

Comment: Great suggestions and thoughts, w00te. Hopefully we can talk them into at least using your interesting suggestion. @Rafael is exactly right, any change to how the struct is written to the file would affect a large number of people using files in the old formats.

Comment: Rwrite the file reader/writer to actually do serialization and have it just happen to reproduce the memory layout in the file as it is now. You will then be insulated from future compiler changes, and you will have a stable file format spec for future platforms. I'd get a hex editor and figure out the current file format and declare that to be the official format, and then rewrite the IO functions correctly to support that format.

Answer (score 4):

Whoa - that's crazy. So String objects don't contain any pointers? Must not- because you claim this is working code.

Anyway, that code isn't doing any serialization. Its just writing the structure out to file exactly the way it is laid out in memory. The only issue you have is that on some platforms padding and sizeof integral types like int may be different.

You'll have to find the size of the integral types, and use that information in reader/writer for newer platforms to make sure they get laid out the same way on the legacy platform.

You're running a real risk with that code though. As it is, a compiler change could suddenly cause the file layout to change.

Comment: definitely +1 for "a compiler change could suddenly cause the file layout to change."

Answer (score 4):

The format of your data file is entirely down to the compiler that your C++ program is compiled with, and the definition of your String class. You can rely on the fields being in the order they're declared in, and in this case, I think you can rely on there not being any padding at the start, but that's about all. Some tips that might help you out in this case:-

- You don't give the definition of the String class you're using. If it's a `typedef` for std::string, you're completely screwed, because the contents of the string aren't in the memory. I assume your C++ programmers are using some special local buffer, in which case I'll guess you will find the first bytes of the object are the string, and there is some amount of useless padding afterwards. I hope the struct contains an int at the start telling you how much data in it is useful.
- You'll probably find the `int` fields are four bytes long.
- You'll probably find the `bool` field is one byte long, followed by three bytes of useless padding. Only one bit, most likely the bottom bit, will be set.

That's about all the useful guesswork I can offer you. In your target language, make sure to read the whole file in as the closest thing to a byte array available in the language, and only after that, use the language features to convert it into the right kind of thing in your language. Don't try reading it in as integers, as that won't let you byte-swap if you're on a platform with different endianness to the C++ program. I suggest also looking through the file in a text editor to reverse-engineer it and help you find the offset of each field.

Last piece of advice: consider printing P45s (or pink slips, or whatever you have in your country) for whichever programmers or project managers thought this kind of 'serialization' was a good idea. This kind of sloppy work might have been acceptable in a life-or-death situation, but they have seriously screwed you over in a way you're going to find it very hard to recover from. Writing the code to read in these files will not be that hard, if it's only one struct like this, but keeping it reliable will be a world of pain, and they've effectively made it impossible for themselves to change compilers or compiler version safely.

Comment: Love the pink slip comment! Thanks for the warnings on endianness.

Comment: Glad you liked it, but I do have a policy of not blaming the programmer until I know the circumstances. Maybe they knew it was the wrong thing to do, but their manager wouldn't let them spend the time doing something better. There are plenty of bad programmers out there, but companies sometimes like to make the good ones act like bad ones too...

Answer (score 1):

Writing in an ofstream does not serialize data. This code write the raw memory content of the struct as it was a string of char. Depending of your compiler, its version, its options and the system it is running on the content will be completely different.
Even the number of bits of a char is allowed to change between c++ implementation.
Data referenced by the object of the struct won't be written (forget the content of std::string).

If you cannot change the writer code. You must know the alignment policy, the size of base type and the data representation. You will have to analyze files produced by hand, for example with an hexadecimal editor like this one
http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~prewett/hexedit/
, and probably look at your compiler documentation.

If you can change the writer code. Use proper serialization like json, protocol buffer or simply xml.

Comment: Thanks for the warnings on what can change across machines. All valuable arguments for us to use.

Answer (score 1):

The way it's done, the struct is written in raw form to a file. So basically what you need to know to parse this file is the binary layout of your struct.

Basically, the fields are just one after the other, so to read an int, you just read 4 bytes and cast that to an int, etc.

Strings are a particular case. It's not clear from your code whether this "String" type is an inline array of characters, or a pointer to such an array. In the first case, you need to know how many characters each string contains and simply read that number of characters sequentially. In the second case, you won't be able to get the string back, since it won't have been written to file. The pointer will be useless to you.

One last concern is whether the struct is packed or not. Since you gave no indication to that, by default struct fields are aligned to 4-bytes boundaries, so there may be space for instance after the boolean field that you need to account for. If the struct is packed, then each field comes directly after the previous.

So, to make a long story short, figure out your struct binary layout using its definition and, if all else fails, inspecting the memory at run-time with the debugger, or use a hex editor to study the output file. Then write that specification down somewhere and this will give you what you need to read from the file. It's impossible to tell exactly what that layout is simply by looking at the pseudo-definition you gave.

Comment: It took me a while to determine the exact layout, but your tips were very useful. I used a hex viewer, did some experimenting and saw that the fields do occur just one after another. Ints are two bytes in this case, it would seem. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 1):

No one has pointed out something that sticks out to me as particularly problematic (maybe because I've been bit by it). That problem: the data member `bool Usadl;`. `sizeof(bool)`  varies across platforms, across compilers, and even across releases of the same compiler. Common values for `sizeof(bool)` are 4 and 1. This will bite you. It's getting hard to find a big endian machine nowadays, very, very hard to find a  computer where `CHAR_BIT` is not 8 or `sizeof(int)` is not 4. This is not the case for `sizeof(bool)`.

In agreement with everyone else, Chad's team needs to document the structure of the records in the file, and then make sure the program that produces the file writes this structure explicitly, including element sizes, padding, and endianness. Don't depend on class layout to do this for you. That's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Interesting--haven't heard of those issues with bool before! This one was two bytes in size.

Comment: Anything beyond 1 bit (which isn't addressable) is overkill with regard to `bool`. There's a tradeoff here that is completely up to vendors: Should booleans be small or fast? Chars are small but they are not fast. Ints are fast but they are a factor of 16x or 32x too big. So how big are all those `int` objects in your legacy file? Are they 16 bits or 32? (The defacto size for `int` was 16 bits in the back in the days of minicomputers, but they're 32 bits on most computers nowadays.)

Answer (score 0):

The best way would probably be to use JSON or if you want a more robust solution go with something like [Avro](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.0/). Avro has a [C++ API](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.0/api/cpp/html/index.html) and a [Java API](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.0/api/java/index.html), so it covers most of the cases you're encountering.

Comment: So would it work when the file has been created on little endian system (i.e. win32/intel) and accessed on big endian based system (mac/motorola-ppc)? As op says: no way to modify writing part...

Comment: @bcelary it appears that Avro has an open ticket for that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-303 however, I'm not on the Avro team so I don't know if they already have support for both little and big endian systems. The ticket seems to imply that they need regression tests, so that would indicate that they do support different systems.