# This algorithm doesn't work

Tags: c, data-structures, binaryfiles

I've created a binary file with three persons (Code-Name-Sex) when I write the data into the file and then I read them, it work perfectly so..

I want that the next function read all the information of the X person have (if it exist).

Syntax:

```c
#include <stdio.h>    

struct alu{
    int cod;
    char name[30]; //alu[0]="juan" alu[1]="pedro" alu[2]="leo"
    int sex;
};

int FSearch(char path[],char X[]) {
    char Name[30];

    FILE *arc;
    arc=fopen(path,"rb");
    fseek(arc,sizeof(int),SEEK_SET);

    while (fread(Name,sizeof(char[30]),1,arc)) {
        /*Here is when the errors happen..
        The next sentence tell me that A.name don't have 
        the name from the second time*/
        printf("%s and %s.",X,Name);

        if (strcmp(Name,X)==0) return 1;
        fseek(arc,2*sizeof(int),SEEK_CUR);
    }
    fclose(arc);

    return 0
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char path[]="file.bin";

    printf("\n%d",FSearch(path,"pedro"));

    return 0;
}
```

---

The output is the following:

> pedro and juan.pedro and .pedro and .
>
> 0

That means that is found the first name ('juan') but the second and third isn't (pedro and leo).

**What is wrong?**

Comment: @Deqing In this same program I've created functions for read & write the info into the file and it was successful.

Comment: Your edits have completely broken the program -- now it's writing the `char` arrays to the wrong offset in the `struct`. I don't think you're listening to me, so I'm out of here.

Comment: This is against the nature of SO, but Code-Name-Sex sounds like the name of the next James Bond movie :-)

Comment: You (and anyone else who tries to copy this code) may be interested to know that your binary file might not read back correctly if you change to a different platform, and maybe not even if you change to a different compiler version. Your code relies on *implementation-defined* details of how structs are stored in memory. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11215287/967945 is an example of the kind of mess you can get into by writing code like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Here's how it was:

```
fseek(arc,sizeof(int),SEEK_SET);

while (fread(Name,sizeof(char[30]),1,arc)) {        
    if (strcmp(A.name,X)==0) return 1;
    fseek(arc,2*sizeof(int),SEEK_CUR); //--> ERROR
}
```

### Here's how it should be:

```
fseek(arc,sizeof(int),SEEK_SET);

while (fread(Name,sizeof(char[30]),1,arc)) {        
    if (strcmp(A.name,X)==0) return 1;
    fseek(arc,2*sizeof(int)+sizeof(char[2]),SEEK_CUR); //--> SOLVED
}
```

The problem was the 2nd argument, the *Number of bytes to offset from origin*, passed to `fseek()` call, within the while loop. It was counting two INTs but not the two CHARs (before reaching to the second string). You can see the `sizeof(char[30])` after the `fread()` call, it shows 32 bytes, but 30 bytes are allocated to the string.

Why have to move two more bytes? Because any string have in its end, reserved bytes (for indicating the beginning and end of the string). e.g.:

```
char a[10]="Example";
```

If you save this into a binary file, this file will have a size of 12 bytes.

Comment: That's simply not true. `sizeof(char[N])` is always N, and there are no reserved bytes for marking the beginning and end of the string. There's an ASCII nul at the end (only), but that's included within N (that is, a `char[N]` can hold a string up to N-1 bytes long). The extra two bytes in your file come from aligning the following `int` to a four-byte boundary on your platform.

Comment: @DanHulme Please, create a new answer telling the reasons and with information to prove so.

Answer (score 1):

I would print the result of the `fread` call each time through the loop. I bet after the first object you're hitting EOF on the file. My prediction is that the first `fread` call returns 1, and the others return 0.

Comment: It's not correct. When I print fread, this return true until the thirty time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your binary file format.
Your code tell the binary file have names only with 30 characters.

```
    struct alu{
        int cod;
        char name[30]; //juan - pedro - leo
        int sex;
    };
```

This structure size is not 38 bytes.

Check structure size.

```
printf("%d", sizeof(struct alu));
```

structure size depend on your compiler option...

If your binary format has bellow format.

```
{ // 1st record
  cod = 10
  names[30] = "juan"
  sex = 1
}
{ // 2nd record
  cod = 20
  names[30] = "pedro"
  sex = 1
}
{ // 3rd record
  cod = 12
  names[30] = "leo"
  sex = 2
}
```

See your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>    

#pragma pack(push, 1) or 4 or 8 depend on your binary format.
    struct alu{
        int cod;
        char name[30]; //juan - pedro - leo
        int sex;
    };
#pragma pack(pop)


int FSearch(char path[],char X[]) {
    char Name[30];
    struct alu A;

    FILE *arc;
    arc=fopen(path,"rb");
    //fseek(arc,sizeof(char[30]),SEEK_SET);
    fseek(arc,0,SEEK_SET); // first record.

    //while (fread(Name,sizeof(char[30]),1,arc)) {
    while (fread(A,sizeof(A),1,arc)) {
        /*Here is when the errors happen..
        The next sentence tell me that A.name don't have 
        the name from the second time*/
        printf("%s and %s.",X,A.name);

        if (strcmp(A.name,X)==0) {
            printf("Information of %s:\n",X);
            //fshow_str(A);
            fclose(arc);
            return 1; // found
        }
    }
    fclose(arc);
    return 0; // not found
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char path[]="file.bin";

    printf("\n%d",FSearch(path,"pedro"));

    return 0;
}
```

---

cod size depend on compiler OPTION!!!

```
int FSearch(char path[],char X[]) {
    char Name[30];
    struct alu A;

    FILE *arc;
    arc=fopen(path,"rb");
    fseek(arc,0,SEEK_SET); // first record.

    //while (fread(Name,sizeof(char[30]),1,arc)) {
    while (1) {
        //if ( -1 == fseek(arc,4,SEEK_CUR)) // Important!!! case structure pack(4) for skip cod or
        //    break;
        if ( -1 == fseek(arc,8,SEEK_CUR)) // Important!!! case structure pack(8) for skip cod
            break;

        if (!fread(Name,sizeof(Name),1,arc))
            break;

        A.name = Name;

        /*Here is when the errors happen..
        The next sentence tell me that A.name don't have 
        the name from the second time*/
        printf("%s and %s.",X,A.name);

        if (strcmp(A.name,X)==0) {
            printf("Information of %s:\n",X);
            //fshow_str(A);
            fclose(arc);
            return 1; // found
        }
    }

        //if ( -1 == fseek(arc,4,SEEK_CUR)) // Important!!! case structure pack(4) for skip sex or
        //    break;
        if ( -1 == fseek(arc,8,SEEK_CUR)) // Important!!! case structure pack(8) for skip sex
            break;

    fclose(arc);
    return 0; // not found
}
```

---

Binary file and structure are alined with 4 bytes.

```
// Attention! pragma pack(push, 4) needs!!!
// Your now running machine is 32 bits system.
// This source code will invoke addressing fault 64 bits NON Intel processor.
#pragma pack(push, 4) // align 4 bytes.
    struct alu{
        int cod; // Integer type. 4 bytes on 32bits system. but 8 bytes on 64 bits system. 
                 // I recommend using "long" type. "long" type is 4 bytes on any system.
        char name[30]; //juan - pedro - leo
        int sex; // also, Integer type.
    };
#pragma pack(pop)

int FSearch(char path[],char X[]) {
    char Name[30];
    struct alu A;

    FILE *arc;
    arc=fopen(path,"rb");
    fseek(arc,0,SEEK_SET); // first record.

    //while (fread(Name,sizeof(char[30]),1,arc)) {
    while (1) {
        if ( -1 == fseek(arc,4,SEEK_CUR)) // Skip "cod" 4 bytes.
            break;
        if (!fread(Name,sizeof(Name),1,arc)) // Read "name" 30 bytes.
            break;
        if ( -1 == fseek(arc,2,SEEK_CUR)) // Skip "name"'s aligned 2 bytes.
            break;

        A.name = Name;

        /*Here is when the errors happen..
        The next sentence tell me that A.name don't have 
        the name from the second time*/
        printf("%s and %s.",X,A.name);

        if (strcmp(A.name,X)==0) {
            printf("Information of %s:\n",X);
            //fshow_str(A);
            fclose(arc);
            return 1; // found
        }
    }

    if ( -1 == fseek(arc,4,SEEK_CUR)) // Skip "sex" 4 bytes.
       break;

    fclose(arc);
    return 0; // not found
}
```

Comment: I've update my ask.. Your answer work but is not my goal use a structure to read but: read a string, condition, fseek.. read a string, condition..  I have declared the structure for explanatory purposes. And your binary file format is correct.

Comment: You should know your binary pack size. pack(1), record.cod size is 4 bytes. pack(2), record.cod size is 4 bytes. pack(4), record.cod size is 4 bytes. pack(8), record.cod size is 8 bytes. So you should read a record... This is safer way.

Comment: structure size depend on compiler option. You should know 'pack' size  the binary file creation. I recommend json or XML format for your data file.

Comment: It's not more easy tell you the file size and divide this by 3 (number of structures)? 120/3=40b

Comment: if pack size is 8 => your structure size is 8(cod) + 32(name) + 8(sex) = 48 bytes.

Comment: if pack size is 16 => your structure size is 16(cod) + 32(name) + 16(sex) = 64 bytes.

Comment: You are developing embedded machine. the pack size may be 4 bytes. your structure size is 4(cod) + 32(name) + 4(sex) = 40 bytes

Comment: You are developing "intel low memory" embedded machine. the pack size may be 1 bytes. your structure size is 4(cod) + 30(name) + 4(sex) = 38 bytes

Comment: #pragma pack (1) will invoke runtime addressing fault on ARM machine (iPhone, Android). Intel 80x80 not invoke runtime addressing fault.

Comment: I discovered that the size of int is 4b (everyone), 8b total.

Comment: Yes. right. sizeof(int) return 4. But structure member data aligned 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 bytes... Check sizeof(struct alu). It may be 38, 40, 48 or 64 bytes.

Comment: I printed the size of the struct and is 40b. Now what is I supposed to do?

Comment: OK. { cod:4bytes, name:32bytes(30+2,4*8), sex:4bytes } = 40 bytes.

Comment: Your compiler option or "#pragma pack" is 4. the structure members are aligned with 4 bytes.

Comment: Who did create the binary file? Is it also aligned with 4 bytes?

Comment: I assign your binary file aligned with 4 bytes. I am appending new reading code.

Comment: Who did I to create the binary file? The same way there I'm reading it, also aligned with 4 bytes. Have you read my answer?

Comment: Ok. I read it. See "Binary file and structure are alined with 4 bytes." sample code. read fseek code.

Comment: You're right. Your code work! And thanks for help, it was useful.

Answer (score -1):

`printf` in `main()` printed the **return value** of `FSearch()`, if you want to see if the result is found, should at least return a bool value in `FSearch()`

Comment: Go back and read the code; `FSearch()` tries to print its own result. The `printf` in `main` is irrelevant.